# CSS z-index not working on parent element

Tags: html, css

I have the following code where I'm trying to display `div` with `class="one"` above all it's child `div`s (so the whole element appears red). But that does not seem to be happening. How do I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/nordy/15heL6gf/

```
 <div class="one">
        <div class="two">This is two</div>
        <div class="two">This is two
            <div class="three">This is three</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one {
    border:1px solid black;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5
 }

.two {
    background:green;
    position:relative;
 }

.three {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: `z-index` usually only works relative to their sibling elements. Elements that have been pulled out of the natural layout flow (for example, via `position: absolute`) are exceptions.

Comment: To be clear you would like to have background of child red? And still see the written of the child?

Comment: Why closing ? the duplicate is ok, but this is not the only way.... Easy way using `display:contents` https://codepen.io/Maxigui/pen/rNLdmKX (Note that will not work on IE)

Answer (score 0):

When declaring `z-index` to a parent element it effects his childs also -
So you can't make the parent overlap it's own content using z-index.

Try use `opacity` (etc) instead.

You can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index) for more info about `z-index` with practical use cases.